# How to group by on two tables and apply aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Schema: ([original res](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rCBeUkUbu1BzZIAo2A12hDlw91EV9H07/view?usp=sharing))

[image]

How do I apply aggregate function on two tables while grouping them at the same time?
I want table of blood group and amount that needs to be ordered if not satisfied by Donors.
In the above schema, query should return A+ 14 as Acceptor requirement is 15 and Donor provides only 1. All other blood groups satisfy.
Please suggest a way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note for the future, we prefer text over images since we can't copy/paste from an image to provide an example. Also, the image depicts the data, not a schema which would include the column definitions, not example data. But, to answer your question, it is possible to relate the two tables and get the aggregate you are looking for. What have you tried so far? What do you mean by *"All other blood groups satisfy"*?

Comment: Hi Sloan, I meant to say was that for all other blood groups Acceptor sum for a particular blood group is met by and is less than Donor sum of the same blood group.

Comment: For example, Acceptor for AB+ requires 11 and Donor provides AB+ 19 so no need to order AB+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT bg, SUM(total)
FROM
(
    (SELECT bg, SUM(amount) AS total FROM Donor GROUP BY bg) UNION
    (SELECT bg, -SUM(amount) AS total FROM Acceptor GROUP BY bg)
) a
GROUP BY bg
HAVING SUM(total) < 0;
```

This will get you (A+, -14) denoting a deficiency of 14 for the A+ group.

This works by first summing up the available blood groups in Donor, then taking the negative sum of the available blood groups in Acceptor, then once again adding it all up.

You can get all of the results by removing the `HAVING` clause, or you can get the result you requested originally by `SELECT`ing `-SUM(total)` instead of `SUM(total)`.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you for a clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

A simple join on the BG column with a group by on same will show the results you are looking for

**CREATE EXAMPLE TABLES**

```
create table `donor` (
    `did` int(10) ,
    `name` varchar(30),
    `gender` varchar(1),
    `city` varchar(30),
    `bg` varchar(4),
    `amount` int(10)
);
create table `acceptor` (
    `did` int(10),
    `name` varchar(30),
    `gender` varchar(1),
    `city` varchar(30),
    `bg` varchar(4),
    `amount` int(10)
);
```

**ADD EXAMPLE DATA**

```
insert into `donor`
(`name`,`gender`,`city`,`bg`,`amount`)
VALUES
('MARIA','F','Warne,NH','AB+',7),
('RUBY','F','East Natchitoche, PA','AB+',3),
('CHARLES','M','East Natchitoche, PA','A-',6),
('DOROTHY','F','East Natchitoche, PA','AB+',9),
('MICHAEL','M','Warne,NH','A+',1);

insert into `acceptor`
(`name`,`gender`,`city`,`bg`,`amount`)
VALUES
('LINDA','F','Warne,NH','A+',9),
('CHARLES','M','Warne,NH','AB+',8),
('RICHARD','M','East Natchitoche, PA','AB+',3),
('LINDA','F','East Natchitoche, PA','A+',1),
('PATRICIA','F','Warne,NH','A+',5);
```

**EXAMPLE QUERY:**

```
select 
    a.`bg`,
    sum(a.`amount`) as `num donor units`,
    sum(b.`amount`) as `num acceptor units`
from `donor` a
join `acceptor` b
    on a.`bg` = b.`bg`
GROUP BY a.`bg`;
```

---

**RESULTS**

```
| bg  | num donor units | num acceptor units |
| --- | --------------- | ------------------ |
| A+  | 3               | 15                 |
| AB+ | 38              | 33                 |
```

---

**Another query that produces an Order Report:**

```
select 
    a.`bg`,
    sum(a.`amount`) as `num donor units`,
    sum(b.`amount`) as `num acceptor units`,
    if(sum(a.`amount`) < sum(b.`amount`),
        CONCAT('Order ',sum(b.`amount`) - sum(a.`amount`),' Units'),
        'None Needed') as 'Ordering'
from `donor` a
join `acceptor` b
    on a.`bg` = b.`bg`
GROUP BY a.`bg`;
```

**Results**

```
| bg  | num donor units | num acceptor units | Ordering       |
| --- | --------------- | ------------------ | -------------- |
| A+  | 3               | 15                 | Order 12 Units |
| AB+ | 38              | 33                 | None Needed    |
```

---